# Getting a method to return an image in python

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I'm trying to create a class that has a method that creates a histogram. However, when I create an object of the class a histogram is not returned and what appears to be an address of the graph is returned instead. I'm not sure how to fix the issue. If anyone can please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix the issue I would appreciate it.
Just to clarify when I create an object of the class and call the method stacked_histogram I want an image of a histogram to be returned.
widge1 is my dataset.

The output I'm currently getting is: <**main**.graphs object at 0x11b9536a0>

```
class graphs: 
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    
    def __init__(stuff, quantVar1, qualVar1, qualVar2):  #stuff isn't a pass by value parameter but it allows you to reference 
        stuff.A = quantVar1   #JOBSAT           #stuff is saying inside the class
        #stuff.B = quantVar2    #YRONJOB
        stuff.C = qualVar1     #GENDER
        stuff.D = qualVar2     #POSITION
        #stuff.E = qualVar3     #PLANT

# simple calculation 
    def stack_histogram(self):
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        bins = np.array([4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5])
        plt = plt.figure() 
        plt.hist(widge1[stuff.A], bins, color = "red")
        plt.hist(widge1[widge1[stuff.D]!='HRLY'][stuff.A], bins, color = 'yellow')
        plt.hist(widge1[widge1[stuff.D]=='HRLY'][stuff.A], bins, color = "orange")
        plt.hist(widge1[widge1[stuff.C]!='M'][stuff.A], bins, color = 'green')
        plt.hist(widge1[widge1[stuff.C]=='M'][stuff.A], bins, color = "blue")
        return plt.show()
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

histo_test = graphs('JOBSTAT', 'Gender', 'POSITION')
histo_test
print(histo_test)

#print(histo_test.stack_histogram)
```

Comment: At no point in your code, not even the commented-out line at the end, are you actually *calling* the `stack_histogram()` method.  You need a pair of parentheses after the reference to the method to do that.

Comment: When you do `print(histo_test)`, it's printing out a literal `graphs` object. Did you mean to do `print(histo_test.stack_histogram())`? The commented-out line, `print(histo_test.stack_histogram)`, is not _calling_ `stack_histogram`, it's literally printing the _function_ itself. You have to add `()` at the end of the function in order to call it, and thus get the value that it returns.